# Proof of a measure as finitely additive but not countable additive

Tags: measure-theory

I am (self) studying probability theory and measure using the book from Ash, R. et al. [[1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120652021)]. I am trying to solve one of the basic problems (Section 1.2, problem 3) but with no avail...here is the link to the problem:

Let $\Omega$ be a countable infinite set, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be the field consisting of all finite subsets of $\Omega$ and their complements. If $A$ is finite, set $\mu(A) = 0$, and if $A^{c}$ is finite, set $\mu(A) = 1$.

(a) show that $\mu$ is finitely additive but not countable additive.

(b) show that $\Omega$ is the limit of an increasing sequence of sets $A_{n} \in \mathcal{F}$, with $\mu(A_{n}) = 0$ for all $n$, but $\mu(\Omega)=1$

I would like to get some help as where to begin with...

Comment: Please write the problem formulation directly into the question.

Comment: Here $\mu$ is not a measure as $\mathcal{F}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. The $\sigma$-algebra generated by the finite subsets would be the whole power set.

Answer (score 2):

For finite additivity $\mu (A \cup B) =\mu (A) +\mu (B)$ just consider the cases where both sets are finite sets, bot have finite complements and one is finite , the other having finite complement. Now let $x_1,x_2,...$ be the distinct points of the space and note that $\mu (\{x_1\} \cup \{x_2\} \cup ....)=1$ whereas $\sum \mu (\{x_i\})=0$. ( It is understood that '$A$ has finite complement' includes the case when the complement is empty).

Comment: I have understood that $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ iff $A$ and $B$ are disjoints. Yet, in the problem there is no explicit mention of it....why have you assumed this?

Comment: @mgbacher What's the definition of "finitely additive"?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, according to the book I am using it says in Theorem 1.2.5: (a) $\mu(\emptyset)=0$, (b) $\mu(A\cup B)+\mu(A\cap B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$, for all $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$, (c) if $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$, and $B \subset A$, then, $\mu(A) = \mu(B) + \mu(A-B)$, (d) if $\mu$ is a measure, $\mu(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\mu(A_{n})}$....

Comment: @mgbacher That has nothing to do with my question! What is the _definition_ of the phrase "finitely additive"?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, the measure of the union of $n$ disjoint sets equals the sum of the measures of each one of the $n$ disjoint sets...

Comment: @mgbacher Right. So that explains why Rava was allowed to assume that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint when he was showing that $\mu$ was finitely additive,  right?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I get tit. Yet, If $A$ and $B$ would be infinite, then, $\mu(A \cup B) = 1$, but it does not longer equal $\mu(A) + \mu(B)$, since it would be missing the substraction of $\mu(A \cap B)$, which is 1...anyway, I guess I saw the point. Thanks!

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are infinite _and_ $A,B\in\mathcal F$ then $A$ and $B$ cannot  be disjoint. _So_ in proving that $\mu$ is finitely additive the case where $A$ and $B$ are both infinite simply doesn't come up.